# Redis cluster with more than one machine using docker

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I am using redis-5 and I have created redis cluster with 6 node across three different machines each having master-slave pair which worked fine [referred this article](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) .

My goal is to create similar structure as above **i.e to sacle a redis database across mulitple machines(nodes) using docker**, i tried some solutions refered by [link1](https://medium.com/commencis/creating-redis-cluster-using-docker-67f65545796d), 
[link2](https://get-reddie.com/blog/redis4-cluster-docker-compose/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIov-a9OL03wIVkDUrCh0_TgJwEAAYASAAEgLDVPD_) is it currently possible using docker to achive this ?

A little guidance will extremely helpfull